# How to fix wrong procedural grid with normalized values in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I have problem with normalized values when creating procedural grid in Unity. I have been following great tutorial from [catlikecoding](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/) and I dumped in to weird behaving when I tried to use normalized values for my vertices. In some cases of xSize and ySize grid combinations all works, but in other combinations mesh get deformed. Let me give you couple of examples

- xSize = 35; ySize = 25; // OK
- xSize = 350; ySize = 250; // NOT OK
- xSize = 150; ySize = 250; // OK
- xSize = 350; ySize = 200; // NOT OK
- xSize = 1000; ySize = 750; // NOT OK

First 2 cases I illustrated with sphere representing each 10th vertices.
[35x25 case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc3u8.png)
[350x250 case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23lTu.png)

I am using Unity3d 2018.3

```
    private void Generate()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.name = "Procedural Grid";

        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (ySize + 1)];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        float multX = 1 / (float)xSize;
        float multY = 1 / (float)ySize;

        for (int i = 0, y = 0; y <= ySize; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++, i++)
            {
                //vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y);
                var xNormalized = x * multX;
                var yNormalized = y * multY;
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(xNormalized, yNormalized);
                uv[i] = new Vector2(xNormalized, yNormalized);
            }
        }
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.uv = uv;

        var triangles = new int[xSize * ySize * 6];
        for (int ti = 0, vi = 0, y = 0; y < ySize; y++, vi++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++, ti += 6, vi++)
            {
                triangles[ti] = vi;
                triangles[ti + 3] = triangles[ti + 2] = vi + 1;
                triangles[ti + 4] = triangles[ti + 1] = vi + xSize + 1;
                triangles[ti + 5] = vi + xSize + 2;
            }
        }
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
```

I expect the mesh be 1x1 in every case, no matter which xSize or ySize of the grid I use. Anybody can advise how to achieve that?

Comment: can you try `1f` instead of `1` in `float multX = 1 / (float)xSize;` ?

Comment: I find it a bit hard to read/ understand with the various iterator updates in your for loops, but what sticks out is that in both your inner and outer for loop, you say `vi++`. Are you sure this is what you want/ need?

Answer (score 0):

So my friend explained me, that by default meshes have a 65535 vertices limit in Unity. And I have to nicely ask if I want more.
I had to add

```
mesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
```

after

`mesh.name = "Procedural Grid";`

[here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html) is more..

Suddenly all works as expected. Thank you all for support.